# Is possible to change Visual Studio Code default explorer sort, making underscores come after periods?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The default sorting of Visual Studio Code shows:

- `rma_request_created_for_administrators.html.twig`
- `rma_request_created.html.twig`

[image]

Would be possibile to change the explorer sorting so that `_` come after the `.`? Like this:

- `rma_request_created.html.twig`
- `rma_request_created_for_administrators.html.twig`

Comment: Have you looked into the "explorer.sortOrder" option for one that fits your usecase?

Comment: @Wiingreen thanks, i'll try right now.

Comment: @Wiingreen nope, not working. I tried the "type" sort order (because I want to show folders always first)... it's the same as the default sort order.

Answer (score 1):

A sub-ordering of files and folders will be added to v1.57.  The setting:

`Explorer > Sort Order Lexicographic Options`

Options: `default`, `upper`, `lower` and `unicode`

The `unicode` option will put the `_` after the `.` version.  I tested your example files and they switched to this order with the `unicode` option:

`rma_request_created.html.twig`
`rma_request_created_for_administrators.html.twig`

Comment: Thank you! Waiting for the new version then :)